# Where is my mistake using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I have a question actually I need one `if`/`else` for hide or show one `div`, I had wrote the following function but it didn’t work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   /*show div OtraUniversidad when option:selected = 165*/
  var optionValue = $("#Universidad option:selected").val();
  $("#OtraUniversidad").hide();  
  if(optionValue == 165){
    $("#OtraUniversidad").show();
  }
});
```

Actually works: `$("#OtraUniversidad").hide();`

I don't know what's wrong; I'm new in JavaScript and jQuery

Some help is always welcome.

Comment: Please enter your HTML snippet, so that it'll be easy to solve your problem.

Comment: Good question, I'll give you an upvote, but in the future it would be wise to give an example of your question in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Universidad').change(function() {
        var optionValue = $("#Universidad").val();

        if(optionValue == 165) {
            $("#OtraUniversidad").show();
        } else {
            $("#OtraUniversidad").hide();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gGX2E/1/

Comment: Agreed the OPs code seems to introduce a race condition where he's trying to hide and then immediately show the element and jQuery/the DOM is getting confused.

Comment: `$("#Universidad option:selected").val()` can be simplified to just `$("#Universidad").val()`.

Comment: It's also probable that `#OtraUniversidad` should start out visible if `optionValue` is 165, which you can do easily by calling `.change()` (with no arguments) immediately after you add the event handler, and instead of hiding it explicitly at the beginning.

Comment: @op: Matthew is right. My code still needs some improvements (I am new to jQuery myself ;-)), but I think you can try to do that yourself by following Matthew ´s suggestions.

Comment: @Andrej: I updated the example in case it wasn't clear exactly what I meant in my comments. If you'd rather keep it as you wrote it, feel free to roll back my edit. I won't be offended :)

Comment: @MatthewCrumley: How dare you? No, kidding :) Its very fine and thanks for doing it!

Comment: **thank you, I correct my source with your suggestions and now that works perfectly**

Answer (score -1):

```
optionValue == 165
```

This comparison is wrong, you must use this:

```
if(optionValue == "165")
```

Comment: nanaxr is using `==` so `165 == "165"` should evaluate true

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference. `165 == "165"` returns true

Comment: **thank you, I correct my source with your suggestions and now that works perfectly**